# Delegate Methods in TwitPic API

Tags: twitter, xcode4.2, twitpic

Can anyone explain about delegate methods in TwitPic API and tell me the architecture of those delegate methods, I mean which method calls first,second like that.

In my code I have added `TwitterRequest` external classes and implemented. When I build my app I am getting message **"No response from Delegate"**. Anyone help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include code and some links to the relevant TwitPic API docs. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/02/23/adding-twitpic-to-your-application/ this is the documentation i have followed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code sample [in the tutorial you followed](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/02/23/adding-twitpic-to-your-application/), it looks like this message is logged when delegate you passed in doesn't implement the callback selector you also passed in when you made the call to the `TwitterRequest` class.

For example, suppose we were making a request to update status:

```
TwitterRequest *request = [[TwitterRequest alloc] init];
[request statuses_update:@"My status" delegate:self requestSelector:@selector(didUpdateStatus)];
```

This code would log the message you're seeing unless `self` implemented the callback `didUpdateStatus`. (Where self might be a view controller or similar.)

I would need to have implemented a method in my view controller something like this:

```
- (void)didUpdateStatus {
    NSLog(@"Updated status successfully");
}
```

Check that you've assigned and implemented such a method. Note that this looks to be optional -  if you don't want to know if your request succeeded you can either ignore this message, or implement an empty callback such as I have in this example.

Comment: Cos i dint have 15 reputations.:(

Comment: Well thats ok @jstr. can u explain me about the order of the delegate methods present in twitpic api.

Comment: The `TwitterRequest` class you're using (from the tutorial) doesn't define any protocols and hence has no specific delegate methods (or delegate order). You need to assign a delegate and a selector for your callback when you make a request (as I've explained above).